# How do I say that I am certified in something in a personal statement?

Tags: phrase-requests

In my personal statement, under the hobbies section, I am highlighting web development.
I wrote something like this:

> Among my hobbies, I find web development to be the most interesting
>   and **I currently hold certification in it from Microsoft.**

This doesn't seem good. Does one **hold/achieve/possess** certification?
Can someone suggest a better way to phrase this without having to stretch it out into multiple sentences?

Comment: How about "... I am currently a Microsoft Certified [whatever]"?

Comment: What's wrong with *I have been certified in web development by Microsoft*? That said, I would specify the actual certification you hold.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "I am a Microsoft Certified Professional" seems a little pompous, though that is what the transcript says.

Comment: @Hugh certified *in* web-development doesn't sound right to me. Is it acceptable?

Comment: On reflection, it's inelegant. "I am a Microsoft Certified Professional" is perfectly acceptable in the context of a job application. It would be a pompous way to introduce oneself at a house party, but for this? Fine.

Comment: @Hugh It is a personal statement for graduate school.

Comment: It's in a formal register. I can't really comment on how it will make you look without comparing it to other personal statements but I would err on the side of including it as most would find it interesting. (It's certainly correct English usage!)

Comment: ... have completed the Microsoft <the name of the program> Certification  for Web development ...

Answer (score 1):

*Among my hobbies, I find web development, in which I am Windows Certified, to be the most interesting*

Is that a good solution for you? :)

Comment: Whoops I meant *Microsoft Certified* but you get the idea.

Comment: That sounds pretty good. :)